# package.use equivalent for VIDEO_CARDS, ABI_X86, etc

Tags: gentoo, emerge

You can configure USE flags per package in `/etc/portage/package.use`. Is there an equivalent for similar flags like `ABI_X86` or `VIDEO_CARDS`?

Comment: Not that I know of. What would you use this for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ABI_X86` (not `X86_ABI`) and `VIDEO_CARDS` expand to use flags, you can specify them in `package.use` as `abi_x86_32`, `video_cards_nvidia` etc.

Out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: I don't need it in the case of `VIDEO_CARDS` — this one I just used as an example — but I see no need to build the 32 bit version of every package that supports multilib instead of just the ones another package explicitly requires.